# Cannot set property 'value' of null in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I am getting the following error "Cannot set property 'value' of null" in the javascript named as "item_pricecataglog.js", following the line of code

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_hdn_returnboolvalue').value = 'true';
```

I assume this is because my application did not find the corresponding element in the web page or control.

strange thing is, element "hdn_returnboolvalue" is declared in the web control from where this java script is referenced. below is the snippet of my web control

```
<%@ control language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" CodeBehind="EstimateProductcatalogueBind.ascx.cs" Inherits="ePrint.usercontrol.ProductCatalogue.EstimateProductcatalogueBind" %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=strSitepath %>js/item/item_pricecatalog.js"
language="javascript"></script>
<div>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_kitavailibility" runat="server" Value="0" />
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_returnboolvalue" runat="server" Value="" />
</div>
```

The above control is inside the popup which is aspx page named "common_popup". i have added the control to "ContentPlaceHolder1" which is declared in popup aspx page.

```
<%@ page language="C#" masterpagefile="~/Templates/popUpMasterPage.master" autoeventwireup="true" CodeBehind="common_popup.aspx.cs" Inherits="ePrint.common.common_popup" title="Untitled Page" enableviewstatemac="false" enableEventValidation="false" theme="Theme1" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%=strSitepath %>js/Item/general.js?VN='<%=VersionNumber%>'"></script>
   <div>
    <UC:callClass ID="usrCallclass" runat="server" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhDiv" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
   </div>
  </asp:Content>
```

below is the snippet of C# code from where i am adding the control to this page

```
            UserControl userControl37 = (UserControl)base.LoadControl("~/usercontrol/ProductCatalogue/EstimateProductcatalogueBind.ascx");
            this.plhDiv.Controls.Add(userControl37);
```

Comment: If that JavaScript file runs as-is, it expects to find

`<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_hdn_returnboolvalue" ...>` Does an element like that exist in your client-side HTML?

Comment: what you mean by as-is? not exact the same element but found this in html source      <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PriceCatalog$hdn_returnboolvalue" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_PriceCatalog_hdn_returnboolvalue" />

Comment: and the above html line of code is inside the following content place holder <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_PriceCatalog_UpdatePanel2">

Comment: So in other words, the ID isn't the one you're using in your JavaScript code? It will work if you pass the exact ID to `getElementById`

Comment: i tried using the code below as you suggeted to pass the exact id but it does not work. same error    document.getElementById('hdn_returnboolvalue').value = 'true';

Comment: Per your own comment, the ID is `ContentPlaceHolder1_PriceCatalog_hdn_returnboolvalue`

Comment: did not work same error. i tired this code document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_PriceCatalog_hdn_returnboolvalue').value = 'true';

Comment: i am not expert, i am still learning. you need to tell me what this whole line means ? specially the ct100    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_hdn_returnboolvalue').value = 'true';

Comment: please help. i dont think so its the problem of Ids. because many other elements are also giving the same error in java script.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. The error is very specific, and I have identified the exact problem. Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1guq06y1/

Comment: "I don't think is the problem of IDs" - it's ***only*** the problem of IDs.

Comment: Load the page in the browser, look at the html, find the control, it will be `<input type='hidden' name='...' id='...' ...`.  Copy the contents of the ID property and put that in your javascript.  One of the issues with asp.net is that the IDs change depending on where you put the control (ie if you put it *inside* another panel, the ID will change - so repeat the process if you move it).

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper code should be (notice the changed id):

```
document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_PriceCatalog_hdn_returnboolvalue').value = 'true';
```